# Error of prime guess

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

So, I wanted to investigate what the probability of a randomly selected number to be prime was, i.e.

If I check if it's even, it'd be $1-1/2 = 1/2$, so $50:50$

Checking with 3, it'd be $1-1/2-1/6 ≈ 0.33$ since we've already checked all the even multiples of 3

Checking five we get $1-1/2-1/6-1/30$ with the same reasoning.

So the just the series $1/2+1/6+1/30+1/210 + \cdots$ or the sum of $1/p!$, Where $p!$ is supposed to represent the product all primes multiplied up to the prime $p$ . I know that it converges to som value since the series $1/n!$ approaches $e$. And this one grows even faster.

**My question is, will it approach 1?**

Logically, yes it would since if we go on forever, all primes are accounted for and thus $1$ minus the series should give a error margin of $0$. But checking with the first $25$ primes, it's grows slower than Java will show me more decimals. It seems to converge to $0.705$, double check if you want to. It may very well be like the harmonic series (that is, it converges really slow), but I've already showed that it converges, so is there a way to prove that it approaches $1$?

Thank in advance

Comment: The probability for a number around N is prime is 1/ln (N) and the does aproach 0.  (Um did you mean prabability it is *composite*).  This is the prime number theorem https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem

Comment: This question has been asked many times on this site and elsewhere. You might try searching the site.

Comment: @daniel  I tried, but just knowing the series didn't allow me to find any.

Comment: Keywords "prime" and "probability" should get a few?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't reach 1, it hovers a bit above 0.705, slightly less than the square root of one half.

To put this into a formula we can crunch with Mathematica or Maple or whatever: you want to know the value of $$\sum_{i = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{\prod_{j = 1}^i p_j}$$ where $p_j$ is the $j$th prime.

Let's look at just $$\prod_{j = 1}^i p_j$$ for a moment. For $0 < i < 18$ we have: 2, 6, 30, 210, 2310, 30030, 510510, 9699690, 223092870, 6469693230, 200560490130, 7420738134810, 304250263527210, 13082761331670030, 614889782588491410, 32589158477190044730, 1922760350154212639070 (this is from [Sloane's A002110](https://oeis.org/A002110); these numbers are called primorials, by the way).

These numbers get big quickly. Which means that their reciprocals get small quickly. So after long enough, a bazillionth of a kajillionth is so close to 0 that it hardly makes a difference.

It then occurred to me to use just the primorials listed in Sloane's. That gave me 0.70523017179180096514742302782374, which I plugged into Sloane's. No results. Don't get discouraged when that happens. I arbitrarily chopped off about a dozen digits and [Sloane's A064648](https://oeis.org/A064648) came up:

> Decimal expansion of sum of reciprocals of primorial numbers: 1/2 + 1/6 + 1/30 + 1/210 + ... = 0.7052301717918009651474316828882485137435776391...

Bingo!

Unfortunately, this doesn't really answer your original query about the probability that a randomly selected number is prime. There is some flaw in your reasoning but I can't quite put my finger on it at the moment.

The probability of picking a prime depends in great part on where you are picking from. If you're picking from the first ten positive integers, you have a 40% chance of picking a prime. But if you're picking from the first bazillion kajillion positive integers, your odds are slimmer.

In fact, as someone else already pointed out in a comment, picking randomly from among the first $N$ positive integers, you're looking at $$\frac{1}{\log N}.$$ For example, if $N = 10$, the formula gives you a 43% chance of randomly picking a prime. I'm not exactly sure what a bazillion kajillion is supposed to be, so I'll just use $N = 10^{100}$ for my last example. You have a less than 1% chance of picking a prime.

And, like the baseless fabric of this vision, all your base are belong to us, by the frivolous theorem of arithmetic, almost all positive integers are greater than $10^{100}$.

Answer (score 2):

The error is already in the equation for the fraction of numbers that are not divisible by $2$, $3$, $5$ etc. This is not
$$
1-\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{1}{\prod_{j=1}^i p_j}
$$
It must be 
$$
\frac{\phi\left(\prod_{i=1}^N p_i\right)}{\prod_{i=1}^N p_i} = \prod_{i=1}^{N} \left( 1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)
$$
instead ($\phi$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)), because you are actually looking for is the number of integers between $1$ and $\prod p_i$ that are relatively prime to $\prod p_i$. And the fraction of numbers that are divisible by none of the primes up to $p_N$ can be simplified to the formula given above.

It can be shown that this expression diverges to $0$ for $N\rightarrow\infty.$ (An infinite product is actually said to *diverge* if the partial products converge to $0$.) This follows from the convergence criteria of [inifinite products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product) and from the fact that the [sum of the reciprocals of the primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes) diverges.

We can also use an example. Look at the first $3$ primes, $2$, $3$ and $5$. The pattern of numbers that are not divisible by one of those primes repeats every $30$ numbers, they are $30k+a$ with $a\in\{1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29\}$. This is a probability of $8/30$ while your formula would give a probability of $9/30$.